# NPAPI alternative for invoking external app in Opera

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, opera, npapi, opera-extension

I have an NPAPI plugin which works fine for Firefox, Chrome and Opera (Windows & Linux both). Now, since the support for NPAPI will be dropped sooner or later I created addons for Firefox and Chrome to get the same job done. In Firefox XPCOM and in Chrome (Native messaging host) allowed me to achieve the same for which I relied on NPAPI. Now, the only problem remains with Opera (Windows). It still doesn't support Native messaging host for invoking external application, so what is the alternative for invoking external app in Opera (15+)?

Does anybody know when Opera is going to support Native messaging host?

Answer (score 1):

Opera does support native messaging from version 20 onward: http://dev.opera.com/extension-docs/tut_message_passing.html#native_messaging

Comment: it only says opera 20 should but there is no official announcement.